# How to read node value with Saxon s9api using xpath preserving newlines only when in CDATA

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, whitespace, saxon

Having the following XML structure:

```
<Data>
    line 1
    line 2  and some text
 </Data>
```

I would like to get the content of the **Data** node using xpath **//Data/text()**

However executing the xpath using s9api results in the following String:

```
     line 1
     line 2  and some text
```

Where the new lines and double whitespaces are preserved. That would be the result I wanted, if the Data node contained it's value inside a CDATA section, but it didn't.

Following the Java snippet used to execute the xpath on the Data node:

```
XPathExecutable exp = xPathCompiler.compile("text()");
XPathSelector selector = exp.load();
selector.setContextItem(item);
XdmItem evaluateSingle = selector.evaluateSingle();
result = evaluateSingle == null ? null : evaluateSingle.getStringValue();
```

I would like to have the result whitespace normalized: **line 1 line 2 and some text**

Ofcourse, I could use the xpath **//Data/normalize-space()** to get the normalized String, however the wish is to detect this programmatically: preserve the whitespaces when CDATA section is used in the XML and otherwise normalize the result.

Is there a way to know whether the whitespaces should be preserved when executing xpaths using s9api? Or any suggestion how to solve this problem?

In other words: when whitespace is significant, I would like to preserve them, otherwise the whitespaces should be normalized.

Comment: The XQuery/XPath data model doesn't know any CDATA sections at all so it is not clear why you think the string value or content of that `Data` element would be different if the lexical representation had some CDATA sections. The `Data` element has a single child node, a text node, which happens to contain some white space. What is your statement "the new lines and double whitespaces are preserved. That would be a fine result, if the Data node contained it's value inside a CDATA section" based on, some section of the XQuery or XPath spec? The result of another XPath engine?

Comment: Ah, let me clarify it a bit more: Suppose I want to put some multiline text in my XML and let it process by my application then I could either use escaped new line characters or surround the text with CDATA and don't have to escape the newline characters. 

In my example above, I didn't use any escaped new line characters and didn't surround with CDATA either. Thus when for exampel formatting the XML above with some tool (i.e. Oxygen), the new lines could be removed, since I didn't specify them explictly using escaped new line characters or CDATA.

Comment: I don't understand what the XPath evaluation has to do with formatting XML with oXygen, I am not sure which formatting options it has and whether they depend on CDATA use. I don't remember anything from the XML or XPath specs treating CDATA or escaped new line characters in XML element content differently from unescaped ones. Inside attribute values there is a difference https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize but I don't see how that is relevant to your `Data` element content.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you think CDATA sections should change the whitespace semantics. CDATA is just a way of marking text that hasn't been escaped with entity references like `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Of course, one of the rules of XML is that it's just syntax and you can attach any semantics to any markup constructs that you like, including CDATA sections. However, if you attach meaning to CDATA markup, then XSLT and XQuery aren't going to help you, because they explicitly ignore it.

Comment: Oke, let me ask you in a different way: in my example above the new line characters are not escaped. When I format the XML with Oxygen, it simply removes the new lines.

I would like to have the same behaviour when reading the text from the node. Being able to preserve the whitespaces when these are escaped and normalize them when they aren't.

Comment: Escaping whitespace in attribute values affects the action of the XML parser when it performs attribute value normalization, but there is no equivalent in text nodes. The XML parser never alters the content of a text node (except for normalization of line endings to x0A), and it treats whitespace characters exactly the same whether they are in CDATA, or escaped as character references, or just entered "as is".

Comment: Formatting the file with Oxygen is a transformation, it changes the content of the file. It may do that in a way that differentiates CDATA sections, I have no idea. But XSLT can't differentiate, because it only sees distinctions that are present in the XDM data model, and that doesn't hold any information about entities, character references, or CDATA sections.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was looking for a way to make a contract between my application and the user, regarding preserving of the whitespaces. Since CDATA was respected by Oxygen when formatting the XML, I wanted to do it the same way.

I guess I will use the following approach: if the node contains attribute **xml:space** with the value **preserve**, then I will preserve all the whitespaces by getting the value of the node using xpath **text()**.

Otherwise, the xpath **normalize-space()** will be used to get the normalizes value of the node, removing any leading and trailing spaces and also double whitespaces.

Xpath 2 used:

```
if (@xml:space = 'preserve') then text() else normalize-space()
```

Thanks for the answers!